Refreshing data client side after mutations when data initially loaded using apollo in SSR component in Next 14
So until now my general pattern with Apollo has been to fetch and cache data on the client. Then when I fire off am mutation I do an optimistic update to the cache, my UI immediately gets the optimistic update and the cache then updates once the mutation returns.
A simplistic example in vanilla pure client side React.
I have a grapghQL query 'GetCommentCount' and a mutation 'AddComment' that returns the updated count
I have a component called CommentCount and another that allows me to add a new comment. CommentCount, when first rendered, calls the GetCommentCount query, caches the result and displays it. When I add  a comment and fire the mutation, I optimistically write to the cache using Apollo's writeFragment to update the count value, which is then overridden in the cache when the mutation returns. End result, the CommentCount component is re-rendered and updated on the addition of a new comment.
In a NextJS application, I want to pre-fetch the GetCommentCount result on the server and pass the value to my CommentCount component so that it can display a value immediately without having to do a subsequent round trip to the server to fetch the data from the client. I now do not have the value in the client cache. When I subsequently add a new comment and fire the mutation...what do I need to do to ensure my CommentCount component updates, short of refreshing the route and re-rendering the entire page?
I am assuming that the SSR fetch is really there only to provide that initial value, but that the CommentCount component still needs the ability to update its data from the client cache? Should I then take the approach that although I can display the server fetched value straight away, I should still be then making call to server to re-fetch it on the client so that I can populate the client apollo cache to be able to then have things work as before? Is this the standard patterns, despite it now requiring 2 calls to the back end - one from server and another from client?
Is there a standard pattern that should be used in this scenario? I'm wanting to leverage the performance enhancement SSR provides, but it feels that I will either lose a lot of the asynchronous partial client reactiveness or have to be double fetching my data as a result.
